# Character encoding after shebang in shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, python, ruby, character-encoding

I came across some Ruby scripts on Github.  The first line is the normal shebang (#!/usr/bin/ruby), but the second line is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I didn't know this method of declaring character encoding!  Is this just a Ruby thing, or can I use it (for example) in Bash scripts as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually the `emacs` way of defining character encoding.

It's not just a Ruby thing as Python understands it too. But, Bash knows nothing of it.